# button onclient click call ajax

Tags: asp.net, ajax, web-services

In my asp.net application, I have a button defined as:

## Asp.net

```
<asp:Button ID="TrackHistoryButton" runat="server" Text="Get Sensor History" CssClass="btn btn-default"  ValidationGroup="HistoryDateValidationGroup"   OnClick="TrackHistoryButton_Click" OnClientClick="GenerateHistoryChart()" UseSubmitBehavior="false"   />
```

## JavaScript

```
 function GenerateHistoryChart()
    {
    if ($("#HistoryDisplayType").val() === "Graph")
    {
        var sensorId = $("#SensorIdListBox option:selected").val();
        var startDate = $("#StartHistoryDate").val();
        var endDate = $("#EndHistoryDate").val();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "Options.aspx/GetDataForChart",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            data: '{ sensorId:"'+ sensorId +'", startDate:" '+startDate +'", endDate: "'+ endDate +'"}',                 
            success: OnSuccess,
            error: function (response) {
                alert(response.status);
            }
        });
       // return false;
    }
    else
        return true;
    }

function OnSuccess(data)
{
    chart = new Highcharts.StockChart(levelChartData);

    var historyData1 = [],
        historyData2 = [],
        series1 = chart.series[0], //level data
        series2 = chart.series[1]; //freshness timer
    $.each(data.d, function () {
        x = (new Date(Date.parse(this.SensorDataInfo.ServerTime))).getTime(), // current time
       y = this.levelData.y,
       z = this.levelData.z;

        historyData1.push([x, y]);
        historyData2.push([x, z]);
    })
    series1.setData(historyData1);
    series2.setData(historyData2);
}
```

## C# CODE

```
[System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
    public static List<object> GetDataForChart(string sensorId, string startDate, string endDate)         
    {
       List<SD> result = SensorMapper.Instance.GetSensorHistory(Int64.Parse(sensorId), DateTime.Parse(startDate), DateTime.Parse(endDate));         
        List<object> result2 = new List<object>();
        result2.AddRange(result.Select(r => new object[] { r.SensorDataInfo.ServerTime, r.temperatureData.temp }));
        return result2;
    }
```

Everything works fine but OnSuccess function is not fired. I checked my JSON data format on jsonlint.com and its validated. Could someone please help me find the issue?

Answer (score 0):

try this....remove the single quotes while passing parameters..

```
 $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "Options.aspx/GetDataForChart",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                data:{ sensorId: sensorId, startDate: startDate, endDate: endDate},
                success: function (data){chart = new Highcharts.StockChart(levelChartData);

            var historyData1 = [],
                historyData2 = [],
                series1 = chart.series[0], //level data
                series2 = chart.series[1]; //freshness timer
            $.each(data.d, function () {
                x = (new Date(Date.parse(this.SensorDataInfo.ServerTime))).getTime(), // current time
               y = this.levelData.y,
               z = this.levelData.z;

                historyData1.push([x, y]);
                historyData2.push([x, z]);
            })
            series1.setData(historyData1);
            series2.setData(historyData2);
                },
                error: function (response) {
                    alert(response.status);
                }
            });
```

Do let me know if it dosen't works...